# ASP.Net Web Forms state management advice needed

Tags: asp.net, webforms, devexpress, state-management

In VS 2010 the ASP.Net Web Application template creates a master page with two content pages: Home and About. State is lost as you navigate to a new tab. As a windows developer I'm struggling with how to return pages to the state the user left them in.

My Customers tab allows the user to filter customers and select one from an AspxGridView. The selected Customer id will be used on other pages (tabs) to display related customer data: Contacts, Invoices, Tasks etc. I'd like to allow the user to return to the Customer tab as he/she left it with the filter, sorting etc. still in tact.

I'm aware of cookies, query strings, view state & session variables. However, as the user navigates away I don't know how to capture the user's filter and sort information from the DevExpress AspxGridView that I would need to re-build the grid state.

Should I re-design the app to be one massive page containing every tab? That would help with maintaining view state, but it could get out of control. My company would like this app to become a full-fledged CRM and I don't want to create a maintenance nightmare.

I'm looking for advice on how to best maintain state across tabs/pages in an ASP.Net web forms application that could grow quite large over time.

Comment: Does AspxGridView have cookie support? That would be the way to go, most data grids will have it.

Comment: a tough one to answer as there a several ways to skin this cat.. in your grid example you can persist state to a temporary cookie or AJAX POST values back to the server as the user interacts.. both have same effect..

Comment: The AspxGridView is quite full-featured making it a challenge for a new user like myself. I'll look into cookie support. I just learned how to save/restore layout. Now I need to figure out how to track the filter & sort that the user has applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, as the user navigates away I don't know how to capture the user's filter and sort information from the DevExpress AspxGridView that I would need to re-build the grid state.

It is possible to use the ASPxGridView client layout data. The DX ASP.NET grid control offers the special infrastructure for this purpose:

ASPxGridView > Main Features > Save and Restore Layout:

http://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4342

E2534 - How to save/load the ASPxGridView's ClientLayout Data and choose them from the ASPxListBox:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2534.aspx

Comment: That's it! The term RestoreUserLayout... is misleading. Filtering, sorting, grouping is also restored. For the other part of my question I'm wondering if "best practice" design is one page containing multiple tabs or one page per tab?

Comment: You can always get assistance from the DX team http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=question

Answer (score 0):

Unlike WinForms, the web is stateless. ASP.NET gives you a few options for maintaining state between pages and post backs. A great place to start is MSDN.

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

[How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

I'm not familiar with AspxGridView, but most server controls use ViewState to maintain state between postbacks. You could start by confirming that ViewState is enabled on the [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate.aspx), [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstate.aspx) and web.config.

Comment: Thanks. A co-worker suggested I keep all the tabs in one page. Changing tabs would then post-back to the same page allowing for simpler ViewState state management. Is that a bad idea for a large app with many tabs?

Comment: I would not recommend loading more than one tab per page, unless the content in the tabs is minimal. Only load/display what you absolutely need for the current view. Otherwise you'll be introducing a large amount of unnecessary http (and possibly database) traffic. If you need to persist state between tabs, use SessionState or a database backend.